# how to display data from multiple models in the layout

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

i want to retrieve data from three models Groups , Projects and Userprofile
i tried to create a new class that get them and then call that class1 as a model to use in layout 
but unfortunately no data displayed ..

this is class i created to pass 3 models to the view

```
public class Class1 
{

    public IEnumerable <UserProfile> user {get; set;}
    public IEnumerable<Projects> project { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable <Groups> group{ get; set; }
}
```

here where the data should be displayed in layout

```
                    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                        <div class="panel-body">

                        @if (Model.group != null)
                        {
                            foreach (var d in Model.group) 

                            { 
                                <div class="panel-body">  @d.GroupName</div>
                             }
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
```

in the controller

```
    databaseDBEntities1 db = new databaseDBEntities1();

    public ActionResult Index(Groups g , Projects P , UserProfile U)
    {
        Class1 c = new Class1();

        return View(c);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you are paasing empty object without setting properties:

```
 public ActionResult Index(Groups g , Projects P , UserProfile U)
    {
        Class1 c = new Class1();
        c.user  = U;
        c.project = P;
        c.group =  g;

        return View(c);
    }
```

or:

```
public class Class1 
{

    public List<UserProfile> user {get; set;}
    public list<Projects> project { get; set; }
    public List<Groups> group{ get; set; }
} 

 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Class1 c = new Class1();
            c.user  = db.UserProfile.ToList();
            c.project = db.Projects.ToList();
            c.group =  db.Groups.ToList();

            return View(c);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set Groups, Projects and UserProfile at Class1 like this.

```
databaseDBEntities1 db = new databaseDBEntities1();
Class1 c = new Class1();
c.user = db.UserProfile();
c.project = db.Projects();
c.group = db.Groups();
return View(c);
```

If Index methods already now this entities you can set this properties too like @ehsan mansion it.

```
Class1 c = new Class1();
c.user  = U;
c.project = P;
c.group =  g;
```